# VB/C# Search and Replace with number addition?

Tags: c#, vb.net, search, replace, numbers

I found this question and yeah it works on my N++... But I feel like not fast enough that I need to copy from my app to the N++ and then back to my app.
Example :

```
<DatasetUnit x="2" y="0" ID="18" />
<DatasetUnit x="4" y="0" ID="5" />
<DatasetUnit x="3" y="0" ID="10" />
<DatasetUnit x="5" y="0" ID="30" />
<DatasetUnit x="1" y="0" ID="33" />
<DatasetUnit x="10" y="0" ID="1" />
```

And I want that X value increase by 45. It should be :

```
<DatasetUnit x="47" y="0" ID="18" />
<DatasetUnit x="49" y="0" ID="5" />
<DatasetUnit x="48" y="0" ID="10" />
<DatasetUnit x="50" y="0" ID="30" />
<DatasetUnit x="46" y="0" ID="33" />
<DatasetUnit x="55" y="0" ID="1" />
```

Is this can be done on C#/VB? But well I prefer to VB because my app written on VB. Btw, I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx), looks like similiar with python on N++, but I have no idea how to use it ;_;
Edit : I don't want every element increased, but only the text I selected (which I can get from textbox1.selectedtext)

Comment: Have you tried doing it by using regex?

Comment: Is your input valid XML?

Comment: @RononDex yeah and how to use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx) ;_;

Comment: @AlexK yeah it is valid, well the XML that I posted here is just a part of the XML file

Comment: you could try selecting all those nodes using XPath, and then interate thru collection replacing values with incrementing value.

Comment: I don't want every element increased, but only the text I selected (which I can get from textbox1.selectedtext)

Answer (score 2):

As its XML you should parse it as XML, E.g.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\x.xml");

foreach (var el in doc.Descendants("DatasetUnit"))
{
    var x = el.Attribute("x");
    x.Value = (int.Parse(x.Value) + 45).ToString();
}

doc.Save(@"c:\x2.xml");
```

In light of your comments, you don't need a stream/writer you can simply:

```
Dim doc = XDocument.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
For Each el In doc.Descendants("DatasetUnit")
Dim x = el.Attribute("x")
    x.Value = (Integer.Parse(x.Value) + 45).ToString()
Next
TextBox1.Text = doc.ToString
```

(Your code probably fails because you did not reset `xmlStream.Position = 0`)

Comment: Returns an error : Root element is missing. Oh yeah I load the XDocument directly from stream, not loading from a file

Comment: Root element is missing means the XML is not well formed or not loaded correctly, what does it/the code look like?

Comment: [The code](http://smankusors.16mb.com/private/smallcode.txt) and [the XML](http://smankusors.16mb.com/private/dataset.xml). I want to increase the element after "change only below" comment